# Dynamics CRM 365 Business Apps Page Could Not Be Found

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-365

I am getting the following error trying to access a Business App in Chrome using MS CRM 365 (on premise version 8.2.10.24):

> The page that you are looking for could not be found. This may be a temporary issue. Please try again later or contact your administrator.

If I enable tracing I find this error:

> [2019-10-28 08:09:09.593] Process: w3wp |Organization:9ccba46c-953f-46ed-a842-9d57082ef828 |Thread:  145 |Category: Application |User: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 |Level: Error |ReqId: 0af0ff18-8d71-4149-8046-68a2fa1c54aa |ActivityId: 0af0ff18-8d71-4149-8046-68a2fa1c54aa | Util.GetBrowserReloadCountConfig  ilOffset = 0x1B
>   Exception while getting Reload Count = System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>      at Microsoft.Crm.Application.Utility.Util.GetBrowserReloadCountConfig()
>   [2019-10-28 08:09:09.468] Process: w3wp |Organization:00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 |Thread:  138 |Category: Exception |User: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 |Level: Error |ReqId: 8cbaa7b4-f4ea-4055-9c15-14739e260408 |ActivityId: 8cbaa7b4-f4ea-4055-9c15-14739e260408 | CrmHttpException..ctor  ilOffset = 0x22
>       at CrmHttpException..ctor(HttpStatusCode statusCode, String message, Object[] args)  ilOffset = 0x22
>       at CrmODataOptimisticConcurrencyHelper.HandleGetMatchETags(CrmODataExecutionContext context, Entity entity)  ilOffset = 0x129
>       at CrmODataServiceDataProvider.RetrieveEntityWithRelatedRecords(CrmODataExecutionContext context, EntityReference primaryEntityReference, QueryExpression qe, RelationshipQueryCollection relatedEntitiesQuery)  ilOffset = 0x19
>       at CrmODataServiceDataProvider.RetrieveEdmEntity(CrmODataExecutionContext context, String edmEntityName, String entityKeyValue, ODataQueryOptions queryOptions)  ilOffset = 0x2D
>       at EntityController.GetEntity(String entityName, String key)  ilOffset = 0x32
>       at   ilOffset = 0xFFFFFFFF

I cannot find anything searching for either of these errors. I receive the error when clicking directly on the app under "Settings->My Apps". There are no errors or warnings when I Validate and I have also Published.

When receiving the error this is the URL: `http://<servername>/<orgname>/main.aspx?appid=7c9a6213-688c-e911-80cd-00155d039508#`

If I query the AppModule table that guid is in there.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Something is not right. Can you try the direct url like below:

```
http://<servername>/<orgname>/Apps?appid=7c9a6213-688c-e911-80cd-00155d039508
```

[Reference](https://ledgeviewpartners.com/blog/how-to-get-your-microsoft-dynamics-365-crm-users-to-go-directly-to-the-unified-interface/)

```
•   For Online users, the URL syntax is: https://<org name>.crm#.dynamics.com/Apps/<App URL>
•   For On-premise users, the URL syntax is: https://<org name>/Apps/
```

Comment: I get a 404 with that syntax.

Comment: @user1488803 I dont have on-premise handy, did you play around the url with possible combinations.. if still it didnt work - create a ticket with Microsoft